# The Qualifcation tag is misspelt

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

We have a tag [qualifcation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qualifcation), which only has one question and no tag wiki.

It may be a minor matter but the tag's spelling is incorrect.  Can it please be corrected to [qualification](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qualification)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I edited the question to fix the tag spelling. As that was its only use and there's no tag wiki, I think we're done here :-)